# Joomla JAuthentication giving Application Instantiation error

Tags: php, authentication, joomla, instantiation

I have got an api that will authenticate joomla user , password . Although it is working perfectly in Joomla 2.5 , it is giving Application Instantiation error in Joomla 3.5 . The portion of the code is as below :

function checkAuthentication($username,$password)
{

```
jimport( 'joomla.user.authentication');
$auth = & JAuthentication::getInstance();
$credentials = array( 'username' => $username, 'password' => $password );
$options = array();
$response = $auth->authenticate($credentials, $options);

if ($response->status != JAUTHENTICATE_STATUS_SUCCESS)
{
    echo "Failure";
}
else
{
    echo "Success~" . $username;
}
```

}

It is failing at the line $auth = & JAuthentication::getInstance();

I have checked all configuration like db settings etc. in config file . Can someone please help me to find out the reason .

Answer (score 1):

The below code should do the trick - it's a modified version of the Joomla Authentication plugin (plugins/authentication/joomla/joomla.php).

```
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select(array('id, 'password'));
$query->from('#__users');
$query->where($db->quoteName('username') . ' = ' . $db->quote($username));
$db->setQuery($query);
$result = $db->loadObject();

/*
 * This block supports Joomla 3.2 upwards
 */
if ($result)
{
    $match = JUserHelper::verifyPassword($password, $result->password, $result->id);

    if ($match === true)
    {
        $user = JUser::getInstance($result->id);
        $response->email = $user->email;
        $response->fullname = $user->name;

        if (JFactory::getApplication()->isAdmin())
        {
            $response->language = $user->getParam('admin_language');
        }
        else
        {
            $response->language = $user->getParam('language');
        }

        $response->status = JAuthentication::STATUS_SUCCESS;
        $response->error_message = '';
    }
    else
    {
        // Invalid password
        $response->status = JAuthentication::STATUS_FAILURE;
        $response->error_message = JText::_('JGLOBAL_AUTH_INVALID_PASS');
    }
}
```